# Can I reference a Method from a Scala class as a var?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to store either a non-static or static method from 2 separate Java classes in a Scala var. How should I do this?

It's similar to this

```
// java code below
public class Class1 {
   public Static int f(int n) {
      return n;
   }
}

public class Class2 {
   public Class2() {}
   public int f(int n) {
      return n + 1;
   }
}

// pseudocode of the scala code below
object Main {
   var someFunction = _ // How do I typecast this?

   def main( ... ) {
      something match {
         case Some(_) =>
            someFunction = Class1.f // How do I set this?
         case None =>
            Object2 = new Class2
            someFunction = Object2.f // How do I set this?
      }
      someFunction(1)
   }
}
```

Comment: `Int => Int`? Anyways, you should not use a `var` rather return the function from the `match`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, I'm trying to save it to a var to be accessed in other methods of the Main object. Returning the function works too, but how would I implement that?

Comment: nvm, I found it

Comment: You may pass that function as the argument of another class, and avoid the `var`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found a way to implement it while messing with Scala command line

```
object O1 {
   // the static method
   def f(n: Int): Int = {
      return n
   }
}

class O2(m: Int) {
   // the nonstatic method
   def f(n: Int): Int = {
      return n + m
   }
}

// the _ is to explicitly show that the function type is expected
// Int => Int is the type casting for a function that takes an Int and returns an Int
var f: Int => Int = O1.f _

// Constructs an O2 and gets f
var f: Int => Int = (new O2(1)).f _
```